# get association's association with ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have 4 table, which is:

```
Category -> sub1 -> sub2 -> product
```

the tables are defined

Category

```
-name
-id
-description
```

sub1

```
-id
-category_id
-name
-description
```

sub2

```
-id
-sub1_id
-name
-description
```

product

```
-id
-sub2_id
-name
-description
-color
```

i have my schema defined as:

category.ex

```
schema "categories" do
    field :name, :string

    timestamps()
  end
```

sub1.ex

```
 schema "sub1" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :category, App.Category
    timestamps()
  end
```

sub2.ex

```
 schema "sub2" do
        field :name, :string
        belongs_to :sub1, App.Sub1
        timestamps()
      end
```

product.ex

```
  schema "product" do
            field :name, :string
            belongs_to :sub2, App.Sub2
            timestamps()
          end
```

in my controller i tried preload sub2 and sub1 as

```
products = Product
                |> Repo.all
                |> Repo.preload(:sub2)
                |> Repo.preload(sub2: :sub1)
```

and it worked. However when i try to preload category as

```
 products = Product
                    |> Repo.all
                    |> Repo.preload(:sub2)
                    |> Repo.preload(sub2: :sub1)
                    |> Repo.preload(sub1: :category)
```

i got error saying product doesn't have association with sub1.  Is there a way to make this to work? Ultimately i want to be able to do

```
product.sub2.sub1.category.name
```

in my template and it would output the name of the category

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Repo.preload(sub2: [sub1: [:category]])`

The error comes from the fact the last preload in

```
Repo.all(Product) 
|> Repo.preload(sub2: sub1) 
|> Repo.preload(sub1: :category)
```

actually goes back to the original query, so it's essentially

```
Repo.all(Product) 
|> Repo.preload(sub1: :category)
```

which is invalid based on your schema.